# What is the meaning of {A} and {V} in DevExpress tool tip pattern string

Tags: c#, devexpress

I was trying to understand how to add custom tool tips on [DevExpress's](https://devexpress.com) [chart control](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument8103).

On [DevExpress's documentation site](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument18052), they mentions the following code snippet:

`series1.ToolTipPointPattern = "Bar Series: {A}:{V}";`

My question:

- What is the meaning of `{A}` and `{V}` in the above code snippet?

Comment: And how this question is related to regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11977) (in Formatting Tooltip section) to find out that:

- {A} is series point argument (so, label).
- {V} is series point value.